# Would a "what bit me" question be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let's please begin with the understanding that I have already sought and received professional medical care.

I have in my travels encountered some critter, which had some venom.  It seems this critter was in a particularly generous mood, as it decided to share some of its venom with me.  It did so quite anonymously as I never felt a thing.  This has left a gorgeous and intriguing example of abstract artwork on the back of my leg.  I have looked up and found photos of bite marks for a variety of spider types, and even some wasps and ants.  None of them look even similar to my colorful example.

I'm not overly concerned, but I am a little curious.  If I posted pics of the mark along with some other details, would this community be able to identify the likely culprit?  Would the question be on topic?

Comment: Sounds on-topic to me.

Comment: As to whether the community could identify it: not a clue, but I suspect it might be difficult. As to whether it is on-topic: If it happened outdoor sure, If it happened indoors - nevermind, we have indoors stuff related to outdoors stuff too and your question might even be useful, for sure interesting. TLDR: We had accepted questions that were far more questionable about its "outdoorsyness".

Comment: This question sounds interesting, and I wish you would post it.

Comment: @imsodin outdoor nasties like to come inside to play too... :) I agree it's fair.

Comment: Question asked: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/13086/9109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as evidenced by 2 year old question that is still open [Identify what bit me by the mark it left (note: potentially graphic, but also beautiful, photos)](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/identify-what-bit-me-by-the-mark-it-left-note-potentially-graphic-but-also-be)

*Posting answer as this quesiton is (was?) in the unanswered queue, and the OP posted the question in the main space that validated it.*